# ForcePAE for Linux Live on Pentium M on memory stick

Tags: live-usb, inspiron, pae

I'm a Windows user with moderate skills. I've set a couple of minimal ("grandmother") users on Ubuntu when old XP installations got too tangled with age.  I'm not a native Linux user and tend to run myself into walls if it doesn't happen automagically.

For my current problem I am building a USB memory stick boot to carry back and forth between a dead HD IBM T43 and a Dell Inspiron D600 Pentium-M. I'm using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6 and ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso which the Ubuntu site recommended.

I'm not really sure about the persistent file setting. Out of a hat, I picked 3.5GB out of the 4GB limit (on an 8GB stick).

Now my problem. Booting this stick on the Dell gives me a PAE error. Googling on the problem says that the Dell should work well with a "forcePAE" option. Where do I specify this?  Please tell me where to set the configuration from the viewpoint of a Windows 7 user looking at a memory stick.

Is this controlled in the autorun.inf? That file contains:

```
[autorun]
open=wubi.exe
icon=wubi.exe,0
label=Install Ubuntu
[Content]
MusicFiles=false
PictureFiles=false
VideoFiles=false
```

Answer (score 0):

i need to guess a little bit, but have a look at ubuntu\disks\boot\grub and open menu.lst with a text editor. maybe it`s named grub.cfg, which is more recent name with modern grub.  search for the line with the kernel params - you should see some "root=..." and "quiet" there. simply add that param there.